# My Banker's Algorithm program with REQUEST is not working

Tags: c, codeblocks, bankers-algorithm

So I just modified my Banker's Algorithm program which had no new request allocation.

It works fine as it modifies the Available Matrix as well as Need Matrix.

But after **line 88**  the code doesn't work properly.

It shows **---DEADLOCK OCCURED---**.

But when I try it physically It is working properly and shows the safesequence.

EXPECTED OUPUT :

```
Enter the Number of Processes : 5
Enter the Number of Resources : 3

ALLOCATION MATRIX

Enter the Allocation for P1 : 0 1 0
Enter the Allocation for P2 : 2 0 0
Enter the Allocation for P3 : 3 0 2
Enter the Allocation for P4 : 2 1 1
Enter the Allocation for P5 : 0 0 2

MAXIMUM MATRIX

Enter the Maximum for P1 : 7 5 3
Enter the Maximum for P2 : 3 2 2
Enter the Maximum for P3 : 9 0 2
Enter the Maximum for P4 : 2 2 2
Enter the Maximum for P5 : 4 3 3

NEED MATRIX

 7  4  3
 1  2  2
 6  0  0
 0  1  1
 4  3  1

AVAILABLE MATRIX

Enter the Available : 3 3 2

REQUEST MATRIX

Enter the Requested Allocation : 1 0 2
Which Process you want to Request (0 - 4): 1

---SAFESEQUENCE---
P1 ==> P3 ==> P4 ==> P0 ==> P2
```

OUTPUT I GOT :

```
Enter the Number of Processes : 5
Enter the Number of Resources : 3

ALLOCATION MATRIX

Enter the Allocation for P1 : 0 1 0
Enter the Allocation for P2 : 2 0 0
Enter the Allocation for P3 : 3 0 2
Enter the Allocation for P4 : 2 1 1
Enter the Allocation for P5 : 0 0 2

MAXIMUM MATRIX

Enter the Maximum for P1 : 7 5 3
Enter the Maximum for P2 : 3 2 2
Enter the Maximum for P3 : 9 0 2
Enter the Maximum for P4 : 2 2 2
Enter the Maximum for P5 : 4 3 3

NEED MATRIX

 7  4  3
 1  2  2
 6  0  0
 0  1  1
 4  3  1

AVAILABLE MATRIX

Enter the Available : 3 3 2

REQUEST MATRIX

Enter the Requested Allocation : 1 0 2
Which Process you want to Request (0 - 4): 1

New Available :  2  3  0

NEED MATRIX

 7  4  3
 0  2  0
 6  0  0
 0  1  1
 4  3  1

---DEADLOCK OCCURED---
```

I was trying to add new request allocation for a process in my old Banker's Algorithm Program.

I was expecting it to show the Safe sequence. But it shows **---DEADLOCK OCCURED---**.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,m,reqprocess;
    printf("Enter the Number of Processes : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the Number of Resources : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    int alloc[n][m],max[n][m],need[n][m],avai[m],req[m];

    printf("\nALLOCATION MATRIX\n\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Allocation for P%d : ",i+1);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&alloc[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\MAXIMUM MATRIX\n\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Maximum for P%d : ",i+1);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&max[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nNEED MATRIX\n\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            need[i][j] = max[i][j] - alloc[i][j];
            printf(" %d ",need[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nAVAILABLE MATRIX\n\n");
    printf("Enter the Available : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&avai[i]);
    }

    printf("\nREQUEST MATRIX\n\n");
    printf("Enter the Requested Allocation : ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&req[i]);
    }
    printf("Which Process you want to Request (0 - %d): ",n-1);
    scanf("%d",&reqprocess);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        if(req[i] > avai[i])
        {
            flag = 1;
            printf("REQUEST NOT POSSIBLE\n");
            break;
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        {
            avai[i] -= req[i];
            need[reqprocess][i] -= req[i];
        }

    }
    printf("New Avaialable : " );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",avai[i]);
    }
    printf("\nNEED MATRIX\n\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d ",need[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
**line 88**
    int work[m],finish[n],safeSequence[n],ind = 0;

    printf("Work : " );
    for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
    {
        work[i] = avai[i];
        printf(" %d ",work[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        finish[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            if(finish[i] == 0)
            {
                int flag = 0;
                for(int j = 0 ; j < m ; j++)
                {
                    if(need[i][j] > work[j])
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag == 0)
                {
                    printf("i : %d",i); 
                    safeSequence[ind++] = i;
                    for(int y = 0 ; y < m ; y++)
                    {
                        work[y] = work[y] + alloc[i][y];
                        finish[i] = 1;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    int flag = 1;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        if(finish[i] == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            printf("\n---DEADLOCK OCCURED---\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        printf("\n---SAFESEQUENCE---\n");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++)
        {
            printf("P%d ==> ",safeSequence[i]);
        }
        printf("P%d",safeSequence[n-1]);

    }
}
```

**i is only printed once** in printf("i : %d",i);

The program works up to printing the new NEED MATRIX.
After that it doesn't work.

**Someone please help!!**

Comment: When a Request occurs, Check if  **Request<Available**. If true, we allocate the requested resource for the requested process by `Available = Available - Request` & `Allocation = Allocation + Request`  for a particular process. The problem of the code was `need[reqprocess][i] -= req[i];` as in `work[y] = work[y] + alloc[i][y];` the older allocation is present for P1 which is **2 0 0** . Instead we need a  `alloc[reqprocess][i] += req[i];` . Now we **Allocation** for P1 becomes **3 0 2** and now we need to find the **Need Matrix**. After that the program will work fine